# Items in RecyclerView are different with ViewBinding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewbinding

When i make Adapter in regular way, with findViewById it looks ok: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj8A8.png), but when i do it with view binding looks like this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzIzD.png)

Adapter with ViewBinding:

```
class HomePageFoldersAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomePageFoldersAdapter.FolderHolder>() {

var list = emptyList<Folder>()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FolderHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding = FolderHomeCardBinding.inflate(inflater)
    return FolderHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FolderHolder, position: Int) {
    val folder = list[position]
    with(holder.binding) {
        val context = root.context
        nameTextView.text = folder.name
        sizeTextView.text = context.getString(R.string.modules_count, folder.modulesIds.size)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount() = list.size

class FolderHolder(val binding: FolderHomeCardBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try replace instead

```
 val binding = FolderHomeCardBinding.inflate(inflater)
```

with

```
 val binding = FolderHomeCardBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
```